# Codeigniter: implementing search functionality

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, codeigniter

Error :
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: records

Filename: views/Search_data.php

Line Number: 80

Backtrace:

File: /home/paychzaq/public_html/application/views/Search_data.php
Line: 80
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/paychzaq/public_html/application/controllers/Search.php
Line: 13
Function: view

File: /home/paychzaq/public_html/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Controller :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Search extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
     $this->load->model('Search_model'); 
     $this->load->database();
     $this->load->library('session');
 }

function index(){
$this->load->view('Search_data');
}

public function searchUser() {

        $key = $this->input->post('search');

        if(isset($key) and !empty($key)){
            $data['records'] = $this->Search_model->searchRecord($key);
            $data['link'] = '';
            $data['message'] = 'Search Results';
            $this->load->view('Search_data' , $data);
        }
        else {
            redirect('Search') ;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Model :

```
<?php
class Search_model extends CI_Model 
{
    public function searchRecord($key)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('campaigns');
        $this->db->like('title',$key);
        $this->db->or_like('category',$key);
        $this->db->or_like('description',$key);
        $query = $this->db->get();

          if($query->num_rows()>0){
          return $query->result();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

View :

```
<?php
  foreach($records as $row)
  {
  $sr=$row->photo;
$ur=   site_url()."/campaign_info/campaign_detail/".$row->campaignid."/".$row->title."";

?>
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
            <div style="height: 40rem;" class="card card-product">
              <div class="card-header border-0">
                <h2 class="h6">
                  <a href="#"><?php echo $row->title?></a>
                </h2>
              </div>
              <!-- Product image -->
              <figure class="figure">
               <a href="<?php echo $ur; ?>"> <img alt="Image placeholder" src='<?php echo $sr; ?>' style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; object-fit: contain;" class="img-center img-fluid"></a>
              </figure>
              <div class="card-body">
                <!-- Price -->
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center mt-4">
                  <span class="h6 mb-0"> <?php echo $row->price?> RS</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-success rounded-pill ml-auto"><a style="color: white"href="<?php echo $ur;?>">Details</a></span>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="p-4 border-top">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-6 text-center">
                    <a href="<?php echo "#abc".$row->campaignid;?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-icon-only rounded-circle ml-4" data-toggle="modal">
                <span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></span>
            </a>
                    <span class="d-block text-sm">Send Proposal</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 text-center">
                    <span class="h5 mb-0"><?php echo $row->deadline ?></span><sup></sup>
                    <span class="d-block text-sm">Deadline</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

<?php
   $url='proposal/validation/'.$row->campaignid;
  ?>
            <div class="modal fade" id="<?php echo "abc".$row->campaignid;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body"> 
              <?php echo form_open($url)?>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-control-label">
                    Your Fees
                  </label>
                  <input name="fee" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-control-label">
                    Days To Complete
                  </label>
                  <input  name="days" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <!-- Project description -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-control-label mb-0">
                    Details 
                  </label>
                  <small class="form-text text-muted mb-2 mt-0">
                    This textarea will autosize while you type
                  </small>
                  <textarea name="details"class="form-control" data-toggle="autosize" rows="2"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-pill mr-auto">Send</button>
               <?php echo form_close()?>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <div class="actions d-flex justify-content-between">
                  <a href="#" class="action-item">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="action-item">
                    <i class="fas fa-chart-pie"></i>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="action-item text-danger">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
</div>


    <?php
    }
       ?>
```

Comment: `foreach($records as $row)` Where does `$records` get defined? It is not in your code.

Comment: describe a little more your problem, please

Comment: records are defined in controller : $data['records'] = $this->Search_model->searchRecord($key);

Answer (score 1):

I think it's undefined because on your `index` method you haven't declare the `$records` variable yet. On your view, try to filter if `$records` is available like this :

```php
<?php
if (!empty($records)) {
  foreach($records as $row)
  {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the model

```
if($query->num_rows()>0){
   return $query->result();
}else{
   return array();
}
```